# Error checking C++ streams with Exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, fstream

I have a class X which has a writeBinary(ostream) method which can throw a custom exception
if something happens to the stream.

What is the correct way to write to fstream and error check?

Here is my version: I would like to know if I am missing something or I need to catch 
errors.

```
    ofstream ofs("X.binary.tmp");
    if (!ofs) {
       cerr << "Could not open file for writing";
       throw runtime_error("Could not open file for writing");
    }
    try {
      x.writeBinary(ofs);
     } catch(CustomException& e) {
      // remove the temporary file
       int x = unlink("X.binary.tmp");
       if (x) {
        cerr << "Failed to remove file";
       }
       throw;
     }

    if (!ofs) { // is this check necessary?
     int x = unlink("X.binary.tmp"):
    if (x) {
        cerr << "Failed to remove file";
       }
       throw std::runtime_error("Stream error");
    }
   rename("X.binary.tmp", "X.binary");
```

Can this hodgepodge mess of exceptions be simplified?

Answer (score 0):

One way to make things a lot less messy is to create a resource handling object - so a "tempfile" object, which opens a new file by the name given to the constructor, and in the destructor calls unlink if the filename isn't blank. Then have it have a rename function that renames the file and sets the name to blank, for example. And of course a function that gives you the ofstream from the object.

I'm sure it's as much code, but it'll look a lot cleaner, and it will make life much easier.

Writing code that copes with lots of potential errors is not easy, as you may have noticed...